# Understanding the Difference between Bernoulli Distribution and Binomial Distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, measurement-error, discrete-distributions

In my recent study, I conducted 67 measurements and recorded 11 successful outcomes. Now, I am seeking clarification on the appropriate formulas to calculate the measurement error. Should I use the formulas specific to the Bernoulli distribution or the Binomial distribution? Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
(please take into account, I have read all RTFM).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I need to calculate the Observational error (Confidence interval) at the 95% confidence level. I conducted 67 measurements and recorded 11 successful outcomes. Could you advise me on a formulate (or a link to an article or to a page of the textbook)?